# How to display random images from string names

Tags: php, image

I wish to display 1 of 4 random images on the landing page. To make it easy for the customer I have a settings page menu item where they can input the URL for non-coding users. In the Functions-admin.php I have the following code,

```
function settings_page_admin() {

    for ($i=1 ; $i<=4 ; $i++) {
        register_setting( 'sah-group', 'home_img_'.$i );
    }
```

I try calling it on the home-header.php,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageURLs = for ($i=1 ; $i<=4 ; $i++) {
    <?php echo get_feature_img ( 'home_img_'.$i () ); ?>
    };
function getImageTag() {
var img = '<img src=\"';
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
return img;
}
</script>
<div id="home_banner" class="home-header" <?php echo get_home_img( 'home_img_'.$i ) ?>>
```

I'm missing a step (or more) on getting this right, can't see the forest for the trees. Assistance appreciated.

Comment: You are not calling `settings_page_admin()` anywhere. Also notice that you can't easily mix Javascript and PHP, `$i` is unknown to PHP since it's a JS variable

Comment: if you want the random image generated by PHP, u should call the PHP code via AJAX or insert the generated image id directly as `img` everytime the page is loaded